# Cannot connect to AWS DocumentDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

I am having trouble connecting to my AWS DocumentDB Instance. Here is the setup.

### DocumentDB

Engine version docdb 4.0.0

Security Groups:

- Default
- DocumentDB

### EC2

Security Groups:

- Default
- SSHing VPC
- DocumentDB VPC

### Lambda

Security Groups:

- DocumentDB VPC

### VPC

Has Internet Gateway

### Security Groups

#### Default

- IB
  All traffic from Default SG
- OB
  All traffic

#### SSHING Security Group

- IB
  Traffic to ports 22 and 27017 from my IP Address
- OB
  All traffic

### DocumentDB

- IB
  Port 443 from DocumentDB SG
  Port 27017 from my IP address
  All ports from SSHING
- OB
  All traffic
  Port 443 DocumentDB SG

I realize my vpc is probably not set up correctly. Any advice would be appreciated

When I write a simple python script and execute it in an EC2 instance assigned the SSHing security group, it works.

When I try to execute a similar lambda function as configured above, I get a pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError.

When I create a tunnel locally  via `ssh -i "xxx.pem" -L 27017:xxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ec2-user@xxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com -N`

then try to connect with Compass, the tunnel generates `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 0):

There are several prerequisites required, in order to configure a Lambda function to successfully connect to DocumentDB. Follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-documentdb-samples/tree/master/lambda-samples), which I believe it may help you.